# PHP why I only can insert 1 single data into my database(mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

I can only insert one single data into my database after that I refresh and try to insert another data it will only show 'Unable to register! Please Try Again!' below is my code what's the problem? :

```
<?php
include "conn.php"; // connection
$username = $_POST['user']; 
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpass'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 


 if($password !== $confirmpassword) {   echo "<script>alert('Password and confirmed password not same!'); ";
 die("window.history.go(-1);</script>"); } 

//write the insert sql query
 $sql = "Insert into users (User_Name, User_Password, User_Email, User_Last_login ) VALUES ('$username','".md5($password)."','$email','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."');";

//to check the query executed or not
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) <=0) 
 {   
    die ("<script>alert('Unable to register! \\nPlease Try Again!');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
 }

 echo "<script>alert('Register Successfully!Please login now!');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
 echo "window.location.href='login.html';</script>";         
?>
```

I have try to solve this for few hours tried solution from other question but still not working, I still only can insert 1 data after that it keep shows Unable to register! Please Try Again!

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: There's also no need to escape passwords since you only store the hash anyway. Escaping the password actually changes the password.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Can you put it back before it hurts someone? There's so many things fundamentally wrong here it's hard to even begin to explain, but I've tagged three of the most serious problems above. A proper login system backed by an ORM is not the sort of thing you can write on your own without considerable experience, and even then it takes way more time than you should spend on such a thing when pre-existing solutions work, are tested, and have community support.

Comment: hmmm.... this is my college tutorial actually its ok.... but now what's the main solution for this..

Comment: do you have skype bro?...

Comment: Hi man so what I would recommend checking if you only able to insert one row and after that it doesn't let you add another. Is to check your SQL DB and make sure you haven't set any of your fields to Unique. Unique works for the ID's because they auto increment. But if it's another field it could cause complications. I hope that helps. Good luck :)

Comment: If this is an academic project and you're never going to expose it to actual users then you've got a lot more latitude. I'd strongly suggest using the object-oriented approach as it's much harder to get wrong (fewer arguments, can't be confused with `mysql_query` etc.) and keeps your code cleaner and easier to understand. That would fix *some* of the problems here.

Comment: **Try adding some error checking** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
Check this link. Should prove helpful. :)

Comment: ermm how to actually check it because it's actually works fine and it didn't appear any error message... I'm new for php... some specific terms that you guys are telling I may not understand clearly..

Comment: ok after I adding that code error occur I'm trying to fix it now... thanks!

Comment: the error shows that Undefined index: user on line 7, I tried to recreate the database and retype the query but it's still not working .....

Comment: somebody help me please..... the problem still not solve

Comment: I wasted 1 day on this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that :

> if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)<=0)

is the problem, because it returns the number of affected rows in the previous SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query. after the first insert, it will always be true.

what did you want to test??

Comment: I want it to test is that a row are inserting to the table because if there is any error or something else cause it didn't insert any column of data not inserting it will appear unable to register its mean the user still haven register

Comment: How about change it by :

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($result) {
        echo "<script>alert('Register Successfully!Please login now!');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
        echo "window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
    } else {
        die ("<script>alert('Unable to register! \\nPlease Try Again!');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
    }

Answer (score 0):

as i said above, i think you have an error on this

```
   if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) <=0) 
 {   
    die ("<script>alert('Unable to register! \\nPlease Try Again!');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
 }
```

How about change it by :

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($result) {
        echo "<script>alert('Register Successfully!Please login now!');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
        echo "window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
    } else {
        die ("<script>alert('Unable to register! \\nPlease Try Again!');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
    }
```